# RaphaelJS Icon weird resizing overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, raphael

I'm trying to resize my raphaeljs icons. But i'm having some weird resizing overflow issues, that I don't really know how to fix, but i've already tried some methods.

I have a live link with the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/ydmSB/2/

This is the JS code:

```
var message = "M16,5.333c-7.732,0-14,4.701-14,10.5c0,1.982,0.741,3.833,2.016,5.414L2,25.667l5.613-1.441c2.339,1.317,5.237,2.107,8.387,2.107c7.732,0,14-4.701,14-10.5C30,10.034,23.732,5.333,16,5.333z";

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    paper = Raphael(elements[i], 200, 200)
    paper.path(message).attr({
        "fill": "#333"
    }).transform("s5");
}​
```

My CSS code:

```
.wrapper { width:400px; height:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
.icon {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:50px;
}​
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="icon">
      <div class="message">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `transform` command is scaling your path around its nominal center, when it seems you want to scale it from the top left corner. So the result you're seeing is the icon scaling past the top left corner of the container, in this case your `.message` div.

One fix is to supply a center point to your transform, such as `transform("s5,5,0,0")`. Another is to provide more space for the scaling to take place. Another is to supply an x,y translation to the transform as well (`t50,50` for example).

In general, you need to make sure there is enough room in the containing Raphael paper object for all the scaling transformations to take place. In your example, it's taking the size of the div, in which you have `height` set to `auto`. That means your font size may affect the size of the paper and cause clipping issues. When it doubt, set your paper size manually.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this appears to be due to the fact that a scale-transform, by default, scales up from the center of the object, so it's literally scaling outside of the container that you put it in.

If you want to, you can specify an origin point:

```
}).transform("s5,5,0,0");
```

This basically says, "scale x by 5 times, and y by five times, but start the transform from the object's 0,0 coordinate."

The documentation is here, and confusing as hell. Took me a few tries to figure out how to read it! http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank You!
It's confusing indeed, at first I didn't even understand how to display the icons...